# How should I add offchain worker(OCW) in frontier when using AccountId20?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, frontier, offchain-worker, frontier-node-template

In order to add an offchain worker with using `AccountId20` as the runtime account type I did following things.

1. add associated type `type AuthorityId: AppCrypto<Self::Public, Self::Signature>;` in the config traitof an OCW pallet, and add traitbond `CreateSignedTransaction<Call<Self>>` to the config.
2. Implement `CreateSignedTransaction<LocalCall>` for Runtime like [the substrate offchain worker tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-offchain-workers/) says.
3. create a `crypto` module, and rewrite the sign and verify method (where I used `sp_io::crypto::ecdsa_sign`):

   ```
   pub const KEY_TYPE: KeyTypeId = KeyTypeId(*b"demo");
   pub mod crypto {
       use super::KEY_TYPE;
       use sp_runtime::traits::Verify;
       use sp_runtime::{
           app_crypto::{app_crypto, ecdsa},
       };
       use fp_account::{
           EthereumSignature, EthereumSigner
       };
       use sp_io::crypto::ecdsa_sign;
       use sp_io::hashing::keccak_256;
       use fp_account::AccountId20;
       app_crypto!(ecdsa, KEY_TYPE);

       impl frame_system::offchain::AppCrypto<EthereumSigner, EthereumSignature> for TestAuthId {
           type RuntimeAppPublic = Public; 
           type GenericSignature = ecdsa::Signature; //struct Signature(pub [u8; 65]);
           type GenericPublic = ecdsa::Public;       //struct Public(pub [u8; 32]) 

           fn sign(payload: &[u8], public: EthereumSigner) -> Option<EthereumSignature> { 
               let m = keccak_256(payload);
               let ECDSAPublic: ecdsa::Public = public.into(); // compressed one
               match ecdsa_sign(KEY_TYPE, &ECDSAPublic, &m) {
                   None => return None,
                   Some(e) => {
                       log::info!("[{:?}]: singature.", &e);
                       return Some(e.into())
                   }
               }
           }

           fn verify(payload: &[u8], public: EthereumSigner, signature: EthereumSignature) -> bool { 
               let accountId: &AccountId20 = &public.into();
               let result = signature.verify(payload, accountId);
               log::info!("[{:?}]: verify result.", &result);
               result
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Turns out I've got Badproof error: `(offchain call) Error submitting a transaction to the pool: Transaction pool error: Invalid transaction validity: InvalidTransaction::BadProof` from checking the transaction. The error is caused by that the `verify` method of `EthereumSignature` from trait `sp_runtime::traits::Verify` returns false:

```
    fn verify<L: sp_runtime::traits::Lazy<[u8]>>(&self, mut msg: L, signer: &AccountId20) -> bool {
    
        let m = keccak_256(msg.get());
        log::info!("[{:?}]: failed to verify0, signature", self.0);
    
        match sp_io::crypto::secp256k1_ecdsa_recover(self.0.as_ref(), &m) {
            Ok(pubkey) => { 
                // return false
                AccountId20(H160::from(H256::from(keccak_256(&pubkey))).0)==*signer
            },
            ...
        }
    }
```

I guess my assumption that `sp_io::crypto::secp256k1_ecdsa_recover` is the reverse of `sp_io::crypto::ecdsa_sign` was wrong, or did I do something else wrong?

**And what is the correct way to add an offchain worker in Frontier with `AccountId20`?**

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: @Discardo Yes, I've solved it by using sp_io::crypto::ecdsa_sign_prehashed to correspond sp_io::crypto::secp256k1_ecdsa_recover, but I modified the EthereumSigner this way pub struct EthereumSigner([u8; 20], Option<ecdsa::Public>) and impled all the From and Into traits neccessary.

Comment: @Discardo before using sp_io::crypto::ecdsa_sign_prehashed, I encryptoed my payload message with keccak_256 as what the verify method of EthereumSignature does

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the `BadProof` error even after using the `ecdsa_sign_prehashed` in the the `sign` method of the `AppCrypto` trait

Comment: Do I need to make some changes in the `verify` method too?